# Install Certificate using VB.net

Tags: vb.net

How can I install a certificate using vb.net in a specific store location like for example in "Registry" under "Trusted Root Certificate Authorities". The below example just right under root but not in the "Registry" folder.

```
Dim yourCert As New X509Certificate2(Application.StartupPath & "\xxx.pfx", "xxxx")
Dim store As New X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
store.Add(yourCert)
store.Close()
```

Comment: You can see constructors of `X509Store` [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509store(v=vs.110).aspx). I think there's no direct constructor to store X509 certificate in subfolder of trusted root CAs.